# Trying to echo variable

Tags: bash, shell

when I am writing this code

```
#!/bin/bash
$ n=10
$ m=20
$ echo `expr $n + $m`
$ expr n + m
$ expr $n + $m
```

I am getting following o/p, need your suggestion

```
./file2: line 4: $: command not found
./file2: line 5: $: command not found
./file2: line 6: $: command not found
```

Comment: Get rid of all the `$` in the first column.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` at the start of each line should not be there.

If you're following some form of tutorial, then the text that you are reading most probably expects you to type these commands on the command line where `$` is (or symbolises) the primary prompt of the interactive shell.  We often use the same way of signifying interactively entered commands on this site.

Also note that `expr ...` is an old way of saying (more or less) `echo $(( ... ))`.

```
echo $(( m + n ))    # output $m + $n
p=$(( m + n ))       # set p to $m + $n
```